# java.util.nosuchelementexception in iterator

Tags: json, scala, iterator

```
def replaceKeyValue(jsonObj: JSONObject, sortPreview: JSONObject): JSONObject = {
  if (sortPreview.length() > 0) {
    var keysItr = sortPreview.keys()
    while (keysItr.hasNext()) {
      var key = keysItr.next(); //getting java.util.nosuchelementexception
      var value: Object = sortPreview.get(key)
      jsonObj.put(key, value)
    }
  } else {
    return jsonObj
  }
  return jsonObj
}
```

when I iterate the key in JSON its giving me this problem.  What might be the issue?

Comment: What library are you using? `scala.util.parsing.json.JSONObject` doesn't seem to have `length`, `keys` and so on.

Comment: 1. `scala.util.parsing.json` package is deprecated/discouraged; 2. The code is suite imperative/mutable (keep Java so).

Comment: its a simple org.json.JSONObject